# How to make multiple time while loop Raspberry Pi? Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Can I use the while loop multiple times? And how could I do that? For example, in this code I want it to detect the string "turn left". If it does the button will send a signal, if it is pressed. My question now is how I can make the loop check for other strings like "turn right", "take the first exit" at the same time?

```
while instruction == "turn left":

    if (GPIO.input(12) == False):
        print("button press")
        assistant.start_conversation()
        break

    else:
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(0.3)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(0.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things you could do; for example running the while-loop indefinitely and checking for the instruction with the "if" comparison-operator.

```
while True:
    if instruction == "turn left":
        //do something
    if instruction == "turn right":
        //do something
```

Or you could use multithreading, which allows you to have mulitple while-loops running in parallel.